# updating element back when model updates while using knockout custom binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-autocomplete

I'm doing the exercise of wiring a jQuery autocomplete with knockout.js. The app I am trying to build is a simple to-do task list. My task object has properties like `desc`, `name`, and, `id`. It has a method `setUser()` which sets the task's name & id (basically assigns task to someone.

I've written my custom binding this way:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor) {
        var va = valueAccessor();
        var lbl = va.label;
        var val = va.value;
        $(el).autocomplete({
            source: src,
            select: function (evt, ui) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                lbl(ui.item.label);
                val(ui.item.value);
                $(el).val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The `data-bind` syntax is written as follows:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="autocomplete : {label: name, value: id}"/>
```

All of this simply works well with wiring the autocomplete perfectly. However, take the scenario where you change something in the model, you'd naturally want the associated text box to reflect the updated result.

The simple solution here is to add the value binding:

```
<input type="text" 
    data-bind="autocomplete : {label: name, value: id}, value: name"/>
```

But how do you do this without the `value` binding?!

jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/InUHIwE/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) to your desired observable.

Hence I'd re-write my custom binding as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init: function (el, valueAccessor) {
        console.log('init');
        var va = valueAccessor();
        var lbl = va.label;
        var val = va.value;
        lbl.subscribe(function (v) {
            $(el).val(v);
        });
        console.log('valueaccessor:', va);
        $(el).autocomplete({
            source: src,
            select: function (evt, ui) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                lbl(ui.item.label);
                val(ui.item.value);
                $(el).val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/InUHIwE/4/